# How to make counter for big numbers

Tags: go

**How to make counter that start from:** 
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000

**and stop when it gets to:**
10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000009999999999999

**I have this code:**

```
count,one := new(big.Int), big.NewInt(1)    
count.SetString("10000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",10)
```

I know this is easy for someone but Im newbi at **GoLang** so don't be angry if my question is stupid for you :)

Thanks anyway

Answer (score 3):

There you go

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "math/big"
)

func main() {
  n1 := new(big.Int)
  n1.SetString("100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000", 10)

  n2 := new(big.Int)
  n2.SetString("100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000009", 10)

  one := big.NewInt(1)

  for i := n1; i.Cmp(n2) < 0; i.Add(i, one) {
    //fmt.Println(i)
  }
}
```

Just fit the right numbers into `SetString`.